# Does tomcat kills unHandled ThreadPools on undeployment of application war

Tags: tomcat, memory-leak, web-applications, threadpool

Say i have an Application deployed in tomcat. And i'm initializing a threadPool there,which i forgot to shutdown in my application. When i undeploy the application war or i restart the tomcat. will tomcat kill that threadPool? I mean will this cause any memory leaks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you shutdown the PID running that JVM instance and anything running under it should cease to exist.  Best bet is to restart Tomcat.